# How to match students to their preferred sections efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, matching

Say you have a class with 5 sections: A,B,C,D,E. Each section meets at different times, thus students registering for the course will have preference for which section they will take (they can only take one section). When students register for the course, they list 3 sections they would prefer to take, in order of preference.

Each section has n students. Let's say for simplicity that exactly n*5 students have registered for the course.

So, the question is: How do you efficiently match students to their preferred section?

I've seen some questions with similar matching scenario questions, but none quite fit and I'm afraid I don't know enough about algorithms to make up my own. BTW, this is a real problem and I know the department in question takes a few days to do it by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine whether each student can be assigned to a preferred section, construct an integer-valued maximum flow in the following network, where the three `X`s stand for capacity-1 arcs from students to the sections they prefer (polynomial-time via, e.g., the push-relabel algorithm). There's a solution if and only if the maximum flow moves `m = n*5` units; then the assignments are determined by which arcs from each student is saturated.

```
capacity-1 arcs            capacity-n arcs
       |                          |
       v                          v
         student 1
       / student 2       section1
       /  .           X  section2 \
source <  .           X  section3 > sink
       \  .           X  section4 /
       \ student m-1     section5
         student m
```

To take the order of preference into account, switch to solving a min-cost flow problem, still poly-time solvable (though you may find the network simplex mode of a general-purpose LP solver easier to use) which allows a cost to specified for each arc. Choose a score for each preference level depending on what you think is fair.

<sub><sup>I'm positive that this has been asked before, but scheduling problems are like snowflakes, and I can't find the old question by keywords alone.</sup></sub>

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you explain why p1 + p3 < 2*p2 corresponds to the maximum number of first choices granted? (also, yes, I imagine it likely that someone has asked a reasonably similar question at some point. However, I did spend a while looking and could only find superficially similar ones due to that snowflake-keyword problem you mentioned)

Comment: @fullmerific Oops, I guess I wasn't quite awake when I wrote that. If you want to maximize the first choices, set, for example, p1 = 0 and p2 = 1 and p3 = 1. The point is that you have to make some value judgment about what global outcomes you want, because some schedules are better for some students and worse for others.

Comment: See also p.61 of http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/64MaxFlow-2x2.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could randomly distribute them into sections. Next you select random pairs of student and consider if swapping them improves the distribution (does it increase the match with their preferences?). You can iterate until there is no improvement possible for X iterations.
This is obviously a very naive approach but if your sample is small it might converge quickly. You cannot guarantee you have the optimal solution, but therefore you'd need a brute force approach which is probably not possible.

Comment: That could work as the sample size is not that big so it might converge in a reasonable time.  I'm just hoping to find something more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a scoring system in which if student 1 is in section A the score is 20? (on the other hand if student 2 is in section A, score is 15?

I'm asking since if there's only one spot left for section A, and both student 1 and 2 has section A most preferred, then who ever gets registered first gets the spot. Instead of who ever is best fit (higher score).

If there is no scoring, you can just loop through the students and put them in the section they prefer. If the first one is full, try their second preference, then the next. If all three sections the student prefers are filled, just enroll them to one that isn't filled.

(It'd be different if there is scoring since you have to go with a priority queue for each section and maximize that.)

Comment: There is no scoring, just the three given preferences. The problem with the method you proposed is: let's say section A is really popular so many students put it as their first choice. The people that registered first are the ones who get in. I'm looking for a more utilitarian solution (greatest good for the greatest number) that considers the possibility of putting students who put section A first in a different section if it means, for example, that two people get their second choice instead of one person getting their first choice and another person not getting a section they wanted at all.

Comment: I see. If you want a utilitarian approach, you definitely need some sort of scoring system. You can't tell if a solution is for the greater good if you can't compare one solution from another.